# Directshow audio / video capture synchronization

Tags: audio, video, synchronization, directshow

I'm dealing with capturing audio/video from directshow audio/video capture source (web camera with microphone). I would like to ask you guys if some one really deeply understand how synchronization should be done.

So far I was able to find out that graph using Reference clock which should synchronize all filters in the graph and that audio capture device does have a default buffer 500ms which I was able to set to lower one.

Based on this article
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/medmedia/archive/2007/03/05/basics-of-a-v-synchronization-in-directshow.aspx

I found out that audio renderer is set as default for ReferenceClock. So I build like so:

```
Audio Capture -> Infinite Pin Tee Filter -> Default DirectSound Device
                     -> WM ASF WRITER

Video Capture -> Infinite Pin Tee Filter -> Color space converter -> Video Render
                     -> WM ASF WRITER
```

If all filters in graph are synchronized via referenced clock and WM ASF WRITER deos handle time stamps. I would expect that because Default DirectSound Device has set referenced clock WM ASF WRITER should be synchronized. But it is not. I can see during capturing that Audio/Video rendering is synchronized. But final WMV file is not and I don't understand why.

The second problem I'm dealing with is that audio capture device is ready immediatly but video capture device takes 2-3 sec. Is there a way to handle that so I don't have a wmv which has first 2-3 sec no video?

Thank you very much for any link, help or suggestion
Regards Teamol

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to troubleshoot first audio/video synchronisation issue. 
In fact synchronisation issue seems to be due the second issue, i.e. your video capture source is having a delay in getting initialised.

Some code snippet shared by you, would have been helping for me, to tell you where the actual problem is.

For now please take the following sample app as reference, and hope you won't face any issues.

[AmCap Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your video device needs to be initialized anyway, so it may not always be possible to get "good" picture frames from it instantly, after the filter graph has just been started.

The solution is: start writing video a few seconds later, discarding first incoming frames. For example, create a custom transform filter and set it between InfTee and ASFWriter. Or, separate the capture-preview and the writer graphs (e.g. using GMFBridge, but better creating your own solution).

And concerning the sync problem, could you please explain your problem more precisely? Have you tried to remove your renderers from the graph and look if that helps?